# Is "all praise is due to Allah" as opposed to only some praise, or praise directed at anything/anyone else?

Tags: tawheed, surat-al-fatihah

Does "All praise is due to Allah" in the Opening of the Quran mean that all praise is due to Him as opposed to only some praise, or that all praise is due to Him and not to be directed at anything/anyone else?

Comment: If not all praise is due to Allah, then clearly some praise is due to something else. I don't see how the two statements are different.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of

> All praise is due to Allah

is

> Not all praise is due to Allah

which is logically equivalent to

> Some praise is due to something other than Allah

This is the latter statement in the question.

---

Its negation is not equivalent to

> Some praise is due to Allah

which is logically equivalent to

> "No praise is due to Allah" is false

In fact, this statement is implied by the statement "All praise is due to Allah".

Comment: Doesn't the Prophet's name mean 'The Praised One'. Doesn't that mean praise can be given to other things as well?